# How to Get Rid of Save Password Popup in Chrome (Ruby)

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ruby, chromedriver

How would you disable the pop-up:

"Do you want Google Chrome to save your password for this site?"

I know it is due to upgrading my ChromeDriver to version 2.28. I have seen solutions recently but all for Java or C# and I am working with Ruby which acts slightly differently as it uses DesiredCapabilities directly.

I do not see the capability that I need from the list given here: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities

I am trying to use a similar solution to one I found:

```
ChromeOptions cOpt = new ChromeOptions();
cOpt.AddUserProfilePreference("credentials_enable_service", false);
cOpt.AddUserProfilePreference("profile.password_manager_enabled", false);
```

Has anyone solved this issue for Ruby?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
prefs = {
  credentials_enable_service: false
}
Selenium::WebDriver.for(:remote, url: grid_url, :desired_capabilities => caps, prefs: prefs)
```

Comment: I hadn't but thankfully it just annoyed me and didn't affect my tests. That's done the trick for me, cheers